# Mobile and tablet detection

Tags: php, jquery, html

In slider shows 4 videos, I need to replace the videos with pictures when the user comes through a mobile device

```
<div class="hero__player">
    <div class="player">
        <?php

$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if ($detect->
    isMobile()) {
    $tr = '
        <img src="/templates/assets/images/button_ground_test.jpg" style="width:100%;">
            ';
    $poster = "[xfvalue_videopathimage]";
    if ($poster == "/templates/assets/images/car.jpg") {
        echo $ec;
    } else if ($poster == "/templates/assets/images/health.jpg") {
        echo $tr;
    } else if ($poster == "/templates/assets/images/property.jpg") {
        echo $ec;
    } else if ($poster == "/templates/assets/images/travel.jpg") {
        echo $tr;
    }

} else {
    echo '
            <video class="player__video" height="506" muted="" playsinline="" poster="[xfvalue_videopathimage]" preload="auto" width="506">
                <source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </source>
            </video>
            ';

}
?>
        </img>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I include mobile detection in this code?

Comment: Nothing is perfect, but one google search gives some results, like [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so i used `mobiledetect`, but i couldn't achieve the desired result

Comment: you can do this with css media queries, but it'll load videos anyways whether user see or not

Comment: In that case you need to tell us what goes wrong. "It doesn't do what I want", without explaining it, requires us to run your code, which we can't, to find out what it actually does.

Comment: @Vishwa yeah, i know, this is the reason why i want to use mobile detect)

Comment: even with mobile detect, all the content will load, I think

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say that your `mobiledetect` doesn't detect mobiles correctly? Or is the replacement by images not working as you would like?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no, `mobiledetect` working perfectly, but i can't set it up as i want, when user comes through mobile device, all 4 videos replace with 4 pictures, and another problem when I write `require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php'; ` the system output error

Comment: Yeah, I give up, your comment makes no sense to me. Sorry. I think the 'other' problem might be your main problem... but that's just a guess.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware what exactly do you want to hear? I think I described the problem completely

Comment: No, you haven't. First you say that `mobiledetect` is working perfectly, and then you say that you get errors when you include it. You don't include it in the code in your question, so where is the `Mobile_Detect` class coming from? You also don't mention which errors you get. So, no, not complete. Sorry if I sound a bit rude, I don't want to, I want to help, but you're not making it easy. I think it's a language issue. English is probably not your first language. I can understand that that can cause some difficulties.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, u r right, i have some problems with english, but i tried to explain my problem, ok once again, , the most important thing for me is to get the algorithm, that will replace the videos with pictures, when user enter through mobile device in the slider it should show pictures, and if enter through the desktop it should show videos

Comment: OK, I'll write an answer, but I'm not sure you'll like it. Let's give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Let me be honest: Your code is a bit of a mess, it is littered with errors. So, I'll start fresh.

First make sure you follow the installation instructions of [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net) so you will not get errors when you use it.

Then try to run this code:

```
<?php

// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once('Mobile_Detect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// detect mobiles and tables
if ($detect->isMobile() && $detect->isTablet()) {
   echo "I will be showing images.";
}
else {
   echo "I will be showing videos.";
}
```

You should first get this code to work. Test it on a computer and a mobile device. Only after that is it time to worry about actually showing images and videos.

If this code gives you any problems, then you can put that in a comment, preferably with the complete first error you encounter.

I would suggest you ask a new question about showing images and videos when you have problems with that. One question for the images, and another for the videos. The reason I say this is that a question should be about one thing: mobile detect, showing images, or showing videos. Not about all three at once.